# Set dynamic Custom Cell from certain row

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, nsindexpath

I'm making an social function in which people can comment on pictures.
The only dynamic cell is also the comment cell. I'm using Parse for this.

How can I get different comments on each comment cell?
I tried accessing indexPath.row, but it gives me a error: `'*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'`

Now playing with a custom `NSIndexPath` but I only managed to acces the `forRow` method manually. Result is that the comments are all the same.

- Row 0 & 1 are working.
- Using Storyboard.
- `userComments` is the Mutable Array in which the comments are being loaded.
- The `println(comments)` gives me 2 objects which are the same.

  ```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
  return userComments.count + 2
  }

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  if indexPath.row == 0 {
      let Postcell:PostTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imageCell") as PostTableViewCell
      ....
      return Postcell
  }
  if indexPath.row == 1 {
      let likeCell:likedTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("likeCell") as likedTableViewCell
      ....
      return likeCell
  }else {
      let commentCell:commentTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell") as commentTableViewCell

      let commentIndex:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
      let comment:PFObject = userComments.objectAtIndex(commentIndex.row) as PFObject

      println(comment)

      // Comment Label
      commentCell.commentLabel.text = comment.objectForKey("content") as String!
      commentCell.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "dummy")

      return commentCell
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because in your last bit you are always asking for row 0 section 0 in parse, you will need something like this:

```
else {
let commentCell:commentTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commentCell") as commentTableViewCell

//indexPath.row is the actual row of the table, 
//so you will have for table row 2 parse row 0, for 3 row 1 and so on
let commentIndex:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row-2, inSection: 0)
let comment:PFObject = userComments.objectAtIndex(commentIndex.row) as PFObject

println(comment)

// Comment Label
commentCell.commentLabel.text = comment.objectForKey("content") as String!
commentCell.userImageView.image = UIImage(named: "dummy")

return commentCell
}
```